# Debian LAMP server - How to access PHP MyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, debian, lamp

A friend has setup a debain LAMP server and provided me with login username, password, root password and the IP address, as well as firewall ports. Could someone please tell me how I access the PHP MyAdmin interface via web browser? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure phpmyadmin is installed? Have you tried to acces `/phpmyadmin` ?

Comment: he should also provide a link, but usually http://IP:PORT/PATH_TO_PHPMYADMIN

Answer (score 0):

IP address followd by /phpmyadmin = problem solved. Thank you guys!